# TextBox in DataGrid not firing TextChanged when text is deleted

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have a TextBox in DataGrid for each item. The TextBox is created as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbText" TextMode="MultiLine" ValidationGroup="group1" OnTextChanged="tbText_TextChanged"
  EnableViewState="true" Wrap="true" Rows="10" Width="500px" runat="server" />
```

The TextChanged event is fired when the text is added or when the text is changed, but not when I delete all the contents of the TextBox.

I don't want to set AutoPostBack to true.

Thanks for the solution!

Comment: do you work with code-behind? whats your del query?

Comment: Yes, I have code-behind. What do you mean by del query? I just delete all the text in the TextBox via browser (not via javascript) and then do an action somewhere on the page which causes post-back.

Comment: I realized that the TextChanged event is fired always when the text is not empty, because I assign values to text boxes later (from an array in ViewState). Thus the solution is not needed, I just remove all texts from the array in ViewState and then assign non-empty texts to the array back due to TextChanged event. Now it is possible to delete text in a box.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround add Text="SomeInitialValueLikeASpace" to the asp:TextBox element.